# How to return item in getLocalStorage in cypress?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, e2e

I tried many options utilizando to getLocalStorage in cypress, but doesn't worked

```
 cy.getLocalStorage('quanta_current_user').then((storageTest) => {       
 cy.log(storageTest)
```

if i use only 'quanta_current_user' i can get all response from getStorage but i need only accessToken item, what can i do to return only the item?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFfx9.png)
......

I tried use cy.getLocalStorage and localStorage.getItem but without success